# Унаследованный класс от QSplitter

Tags: c++, qt

В процессе изучения Qt столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, есть программа "Обозреватель", она в книге написана в функции `main()`, все работает как надо, я же хочу этот код вписать в отдельный файл/класс унаследованный от `QSplitter`, ошибку не выдает, но запускается с пустым окном.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам код:

```
Splitter::Splitter(QSplitter* parent) : QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal,     parent)
{
    QFileSystemModel                model;
    model.setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());

    QTreeView*                      pTreeView = new QTreeView;
    pTreeView->setModel(&model);

    QTableView*                     pTableView = new QTableView;
    pTableView->setModel(&model);

    QObject::connect(pTreeView,     SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex&)),    pTableView, SLOT(setRootIndex(const QModelIndex&)));
    QObject::connect(pTableView,    SIGNAL(activated(const QModelIndex&)),  pTreeView,  SLOT(setCurrentIndex(const QModelIndex&)));
    QObject::connect(pTableView,    SIGNAL(activated(const QModelIndex&)),  pTableView, SLOT(setRootIndex(const QModelIndex&)));

    addWidget(pTreeView);
    addWidget(pTableView);
    resize(600, 400);
    setWindowTitle("Файловый менеджер");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QFileSystemModel model` - этот объект существует лишь в пределах конструктора.
Вы передаете его адресс в метод `setModel`, но после выхода из конструктора этот объект деструктурируется и `QTableView` и `QTreeView` остаются без модели, отсюда все проблемы.

Сделайте `model` указателем на `QFileSystemModel`  и распределите для него динамически память.

```
Splitter::Splitter(QSplitter* parent) : QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal,     parent)
{
    QFileSystemModel * model = new QFileSystemModel;
    model->setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());

    QTreeView*                      pTreeView = new QTreeView;
    pTreeView->setModel(model);

    QTableView*                     pTableView = new QTableView;
    pTableView->setModel(model);

    QObject::connect(pTreeView,     SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex&)),    pTableView, SLOT(setRootIndex(const QModelIndex&)));
    QObject::connect(pTableView,    SIGNAL(activated(const QModelIndex&)),  pTreeView,  SLOT(setCurrentIndex(const QModelIndex&)));
    QObject::connect(pTableView,    SIGNAL(activated(const QModelIndex&)),  pTableView, SLOT(setRootIndex(const QModelIndex&)));

    addWidget(pTreeView);
    addWidget(pTableView);
    resize(600, 400);
    setWindowTitle("Файловый менеджер");
}
```

Но не забывайте про утечки памяти, в таком случае они обеспечены. Как вариант - хранить все указатели как члены класса, а в деструкторе их удалять.

Comment: В таком случае, укажите родителем модели и представлений текущий виджет (this) тогда Qt сам позаботится о правильной очистке

Comment: С утечкой разобрался! Все работает как нужно!

Answer (score 1):

А зачем так наследоваться от сплиттера? Вы же не добавляете никакую новую функциональность в него. К тому же задача сплиттера, как следует из названия, всего лишь отобразить нечто с разделительной полосой, которую можно двигать, уменьшая/увеличивая виджеты, которые в нем есть. Скорее всего, вам нужно сделать класс окна - либо Widget, либо MainWindow, в котором будет весь этот функционал. Сплиттер можно сделать центральным виджетом окна.

```
    class MainWindow : public QMainWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) 
    {
        model_ = new QFileSystemModel(this);
        model_->setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
        pTreeView_ = new QTreeView(this);
        pTreeView_->setModel(model);
        pTableView_ = new QTableView(this);
        pTableView_->setModel(model);

        // connect signal slots

        mainSplitter_->addWidget(pTreeView_);
        mainSplitter_->addWidget(pTableView_);
        setMCentralWidget(mainSplitter_);
        resize(600, 400);
        setWindowTitle("Файловый менеджер");
    }
private:
    //...
    QFileSystemModel *model_;
    QTreeView *pTreeView_;
    QTableView *pTableView_;
    QSplitter *mainSplitter_;
}
```

P.S. и как говорят [Эрик и Элизабет Фримен](https://www.labirint.ru/books/273378/) композиция зачастую предпочтительнее наследования. Отличная книга, советую.